# connecting android app to .net .asmx

Tags: android, soap

```
 private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/" ;
    private static final String URL = "http://mydomain.com/test.asmx";
    private static final String PingSA = "http://tempuri.org/Ping";
    private static final String PingMN = "Ping";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, PingMN);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;    
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);    
try
        {
            androidHttpTransport.call(PingSA, envelope);
            Object x = envelope.getResponse();                          
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {                
        }
```

Error: SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Input message does not conform to Simple SOAP Binding Profile Version 1.0. Requirement R1012: A MESSAGE MUST serialize the envelope using either UTF-8 or UTF-16 character encoding.

I Tried (and didn't work):

```
androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated ksoap2 from 2.1.2 to 2.6.0 solved the problem.